# How come a Poisson GLMM predicts a higher overdispersion than in the observed data?

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, glmm, poisson-regression, overdispersion

I am using package `brms` in R to fit a Bayesian generalized linear mixed model in which:

- the response variable is the count of a phenotypic structure (e.g., toes) that a species possesses (`trait.count`);
- the population-level (fixed) effects are two continuous variables and their interaction (`continuous1` and `continuous2`);
- intercepts can vary over the group-level (random) effect `species`, and species are correlated according to the `phylogeny` covariance matrix.

Since the response variable is count data, I opted to choose a Poisson distribution. There is slight overdispersion in the data, as estimated by dividing variance by mean ($\sigma^2/\mu$ = 1.1). This is how the distribution of counts (`trait.count`) looks like:

[image]

The code that I used to fit the model is as follows:

```
brm_count <-  brm(trait.count ~ continuous1*continuous2 + (1|gr(species, cov = A)),
                         data = data,
                         family = poisson(),
                         data2 = list(A = phylogeny),
                         chains = 2,
                         cores = 2,
                         iter = 4000)
```

When I compare the distribution of counts predicted by the fitted model ($y_{rep}$) to my observation ($y$), here's what I get:

```
pp_check(brm_count, type="bars", nsamples = 100)
```

[image]

This seems reasonable to me except that zeroes are overestimated, as are values ≥ 3. What I found the weirdest is that the model **overestimates** the overdispersion observed in my data:

```
dispersion <- function(x) {var(x)/mean(x)}
ppc_stat(y = data$trait.count, yrep = posterior_predict(brm_count, draws = 1000), stat="dispersion")
```

[image]

The mean is accurately estimated by the model, which means that the source of overdispersion is the inflated variance ($\sigma^2$ = 0.3 in the observed data, $\sigma^2$ ~ 0.6 in the posterior predictive samples), which, by its turn, is likely the consequence of overestimation of values > 3 that don't exist in the observed data.

My question is: how come the overdispersion of my data ($\sigma^2/\mu$ = 1.1) is inflated to ~ 2 by a model that assumes **no** overdispersion (i.e., $\sigma^2/\mu$ = 1)? Shouldn't I expect the opposite: for dispersion to be underestimated? Am I missing something?

(By the way, I also fitted this model with zero-inflated Poisson, negative binomial and Poisson with observation-level random effects `(1|OLRE)`, and the issue persists.)

Thank you so much for any help!

EDIT: By fitting models starting from a simple `trait.count ~ 1` and adding complexity layers, I found out that the main factor responsible for the inflated variance is the covariance structure among `species`. Models perform well as long as the covariance structure isn't included. I have no idea what this means.